# How to run two servers simultaneously using nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodemon

I need to run two servers (www.js and apiServer.js) simultaneously using nodemon. I have specified that value for the "start" key in package.json as

[image]

When I run: `nodemon` in the command prompt with current working directory in which package.json is placed, only "apiServer.js" is running. The other "www.js" is not running.

I would appreciate if somebody could help with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator will run processes sequentially, so the second process doesn't start because the first process doesn't resolve.

Try the `concurrently` NPM module - it allows you to run simultaneous processes - https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

So after you install it, your command would look like

`"start": "concurrently \"node apiServer.js\" \"node ./bin/www.js\""`

Comment: I've personally only used this module in local development mode, and I haven't used it to run simultaneous servers like you're looking to do. Is it working locally? If so, then I couldn't see why it wouldn't work in production... but I've never tried to do exactly what you're doing, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: I'd advise that you deploy first to a 'staging' production environment to test it.

Comment: No. It did not. When I deploy in Google cloud it is showing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157101/discussion-between-skwidbreth-and-naseef-ummer).